# javascript radial list with img selection trying to set default image

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get the none.jpg to load by default when the page loads. Current when the page loads the no pic error display is what shows. I have tried to implement a onload into the first option to no avail.

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
function check_value(val, id, type) {     
    var el = document.getElementById("imgBox" + id);
    if (val>=0 && val<11) { //will trigger when [1,2,3]
       el.src = "images/"+ type + ".jpg";
       el.style.display = "";
       } else {
       el.src = "images/none.jpg";
       el.style.display = "";
}
}
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<h1>Pick a flag</h1>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<form>
     <input type="radio" name="field" value="10" CHECKED onclick='check_value(15, 1, "NONE")'/> None<br />
     <input type="radio" name="field" value="1" onclick='check_value(0, 1, "argentina")'/> argentina<br />
     <input type="radio" name="field" value="2" onclick='check_value(1, 1, "australia")'/> australia<br />
     <input type="radio" name="field" value="3" onclick='check_value(2, 1, "bolivia")'/> bolivia<br />
     <input type="radio" name="field" value="4" onclick='check_value(3, 1, "cuba")'/> cuba<br />
     <input type="radio" name="field" value="5" onclick='check_value(4, 1, "finland")'/> finland<br />
     <input type="radio" name="field" value="6" onclick='check_value(5, 1, "france")'/> france<br />
     <input type="radio" name="field" value="7" onclick='check_value(6, 1, "italy")'/> italy<br />
     <input type="radio" name="field" value="8" onclick='check_value(7, 1, "peru")'/> peru<br />
     <input type="radio" name="field" value="9" onclick='check_value(8, 1, "syria")'/> syria<br />
     <input type="radio" name="field" value="10" onclick='check_value(9, 1, "tunisia")'/> tunisia<br />

</form>
</td>
<td>
<img id="imgBox1" src="#" height="75" width="75""> 
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</BODY>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the correct answer was this

```
<BODY onload='check_value(15, 1, "NONE")'>
```

here is the complete code

```
<TITLE>Flags</TITLE>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
function check_value(val, id, type) {     
    var el = document.getElementById("imgBox" + id);
    if (val>=0 && val<11) { //will trigger when [1,2,3]
       el.src = "images/"+ type + ".jpg";
       el.style.display = "";
       } else {
       el.src = "images/none.jpg";
       el.style.display = "";
}
}
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY onload='check_value(15, 1, "NONE")'>
<h1>Pick a flag</h1>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<form>
     <input type="radio" name="field" value="11" CHECKED onclick='check_value(15, 1, "NONE")'/> None<br />
     <input type="radio" name="field" value="1" onclick='check_value(0, 1, "argentina")'/> argentina<br />
     <input type="radio" name="field" value="2" onclick='check_value(1, 1, "australia")'/> australia<br />
     <input type="radio" name="field" value="3" onclick='check_value(2, 1, "bolivia")'/> bolivia<br />
     <input type="radio" name="field" value="4" onclick='check_value(3, 1, "cuba")'/> cuba<br />
     <input type="radio" name="field" value="5" onclick='check_value(4, 1, "finland")'/> finland<br />
     <input type="radio" name="field" value="6" onclick='check_value(5, 1, "france")'/> france<br />
     <input type="radio" name="field" value="7" onclick='check_value(6, 1, "italy")'/> italy<br />
     <input type="radio" name="field" value="8" onclick='check_value(7, 1, "peru")'/> peru<br />
     <input type="radio" name="field" value="9" onclick='check_value(8, 1, "syria")'/> syria<br />
     <input type="radio" name="field" value="10" onclick='check_value(9, 1, "tunisia")'/> tunisia<br />

</form>
</td>
<td>
<img id="imgBox1" src="#" height="75" width="75""> 
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</BODY>
```

Thank you guys for helping.

Answer (score 0):

... then:

```
<img id="imgBox1" src="images/none.jpg" height="75" width="75">
```

Comment: this would only display that image and would take out the java variable based on the radial.

Comment: What? No, this is setting the default image. It then changes on click with JS.

Answer (score 0):

After Body tag add below script

```
<script>
    check_value(-1, 1, "NONE");
</script>
```

It should be work as expected.

Comment: This didnt work, when the page loads i want the default image to be the none.jpg, then when i click 1 of the radial it changes to the value assigned.